# Avoiding hash collision in php when using sha1 for hashing

Tags: php, security, hash, sha

Suppose i assume if hash collision occur while i am using sha1 function in php .

Will this code avoids it permanently or do i have to use any other way

```
$filename=sha1($filename.'|'.microtime());

OR

$filename=sha1($filename.'|'.rand());
```

If no this code doesn't provide protection from hash collision .

What should i do to avoid any type of hash collision if i assume there can be more than 100,000 entries in db.

Comment: You could just generate a stronger hash http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: I'd use SHA-2 and assume that hash collisions never happen. Chances of getting back the same value for two different inputs are negligible for a good hash.

Comment: "If all 6.5 billion humans on Earth were programming, and every second, each one was producing code that was the equivalent of the entire Linux kernel history (1 million Git objects) and pushing it into one enormous Git repository, it would take 5 years until that repository contained enough objects to have a 50% probability of a single SHA-1 object collision." (quote from the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-1.html#A-SHORT-NOTE-ABOUT-SHA-1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very unlikely that a hash collision will happen for sha1.
Probability of sha1 collision is negligible

And hash collision risk is not practical. No one has found sha1 collision till yet . So you are safe to use it.

Using a salt like microtime or random number may decreases the chances of probability but you simply can't avoid it.

And what you are using is sha1(string) whether string is a mixed value or single string.so using microtime and rand function wont affect anything to probability of hash collision.

Therefore there can be possibility that sha1(mixedvalue) collision might be equal or greater than collision of sha1(filename) so certainly that is of no use.

So dont worry and use this or simple way if you like to, it wont create problem in future, Thinking about hash collision is waste of time when the chances are very very very less.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, you can't completely avoid hash collisions. It's an infinite number of inputs to a finite number of outputs, but you can take into account things like the file's size, the current system time and other data to use as a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) which will increase the entropy of your message digests.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these avoid hash collision.

Hash collisions happen when you have an algorithm that generates a hash of a specific size, regardless of the starting value.

A hash collision is when two different values, like "mypassword" and "dsjakfuiUIs2kh-1jlks" end up generating the *same* hash because of the mathematical operations performed on them.

You can't write code to prevent hash collisions, how often that happens is dependent on the hashing algorithm you are using.

Comment: i am asking if suppose for a specific values hash collision occur .Will microtime() value wont be able to make that collision not happen.

Comment: using microtime() wll make absolutely no difference to the probability of a hash clash because it's a part of the value being hashed

Comment: @asharma: it's highly unlikely that `Somestring + random number` will hash to the same value as `Somestring` alone would. But "unlikely" doesn't mean "impossible". While the total number of possible SHA-1 hashes is very large, there's an INFINITE number of things out there that can be hashed. You cannot reduce an infinite number of items to a finite number WITHOUT collisions. It's simply impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Just sha1() the entire file path, not only the file name. 
Filename xy.png can be only one in a directory, therefore your hash will be unique for that filename.
Also, this has the advantage that you will not have duplicate files (while with rand()/microtime() you can get same file 10 times in same dir, and if it's a 1GB file can cause problems)